# Can these two SQL statements be made into one? Changing multiple indices with two constraints

Tags: sql, database

I have a form that users can use to edit data in my database.  The database is structured like this:

[image: table]

If a user wants to edit both a FAVE_COLOR and a FAVE_FOOD, how would I go about doing that in my SQL statement? I can think of this, but is there a way to do this in one statement?

```
string sql1 = "UPDATE MYTABLE " +
              "SET PROP_VALUE = '" + form["color"] + "' " +
              "WHERE ID = " + form["id"] + " " +
              "AND PROP_NAME = 'FAVE_COLOR'"

string sql2 = "UPDATE MYTABLE " +
              "SET PROP_VALUE = '" + form["food"] + "' " +
              "WHERE ID = " + form["id"] + " " +
              "AND PROP_NAME = 'FAVE_FOOD'"
```

Comment: What SQL DB server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string sql = "UPDATE MYTABLE " +
             "SET PROP_VALUE = CASE " +
             "WHEN PROP_NAME = 'FAVE_COLOR' THEN '" + form["color"] + "' " +
             "WHEN PROP_NAME = 'FAVE_FOOD'  THEN '" + form["food"]  + "' " +
             "END " +
             "WHERE ID = " + form["id"] + " " +
             "AND PROP_NAME IN ('FAVE_COLOR', 'FAVE_FOOD')"
```

But beware of SQL injection!  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365).

Answer (score 1):

You can use case statements:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET PROP_VALUE = (
 CASE favefood
   WHEN PROP_NAME = 'FAVE_FOOD'
   THEN 'PIZZA'
 CASE favecolor
   WHEN PROP_NAME = 'FAVE_COLOR'
   THEN 'BLUE'
WHERE ID = @myIdValue
```

Comment: I think wouldn't work if I want to update both FAVE_FOOD and FAVE_COLOR?

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server you can use an UPDATE FROM which will update two properties at the same time, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
  ID INT,
  PROP_NAME VARCHAR(20),
  PROP_VALUE VARCHAR(20));
go

INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, 'A','B')
go

INSERT INTO MYTABLE  VALUES (1, 'C', 'D')
go

UPDATE MYTABLE
SET PROP_VALUE = X.PROP_VALUE
FROM MYTABLE MT JOIN (
  SELECT 'A' AS PROP_NAME, 'F' AS PROP_VALUE
  UNION
  SELECT 'C' AS PROP_NAME, 'G' AS PROP_VALUE) AS X ON MT.PROP_NAME = X.PROP_NAME
WHERE ID = 1
```

For other SQL DB server the solution should be similar if not identical.